# How to copy from list of files based on first character

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have requirement where I need to copy files from the list based on first character. Below if you see i have three line in list file and i need to copy line which start with M and A to new location for example (destination/testfolder) along with folder structure. Code also has to support spaces. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
cat /tmp/patchfiles.txt
M       Hyperion/Planning/AAAAA/Planning/HP-AAAAA/info plan/listing.xml
A       Hyperion/Planning/AAAAA/Planning/Import.xml
D       Hyperion/Planning/AAAAA/Planning/HP-AAAAA/Import.xml
```

Comment: What shell are you using? It affects the best way on preserving the directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `while read` loop will suffice here:

```
while read -r status file; do
    case $status in
        M|A)
            cp "$file" /path/to/destination
            ;;
    esac
done < /tmp/patchfiles.txt
```

This reads each line from your file, storing the first field in the variable `$status` and the rest in `$file`. If `$status` is "M" or "A", the file is copied to the destination.

If you have `dirname` on your system, you could create the directory structure quite easily like this:

```
dir="/path/to/destination/$(dirname "$file")"
mkdir -p "$dir" && cp "$file" "$dir"
```

Otherwise, you could use bash like this:

```
dir="/path/to/destination/${file%/*}"
mkdir -p "$dir" && cp "$file" "$dir"
```

This uses bash built-in string manipulation to trim the part of the filename following the last `/`.

Comment: Thanks. it is working but only copying the files not with the folder structure.

Comment: I'm waiting to hear which shell you're using (see my comment above), then I can suggest a good way to get the directory.

Comment: Hi Tom, I am using bash shell.

Comment: @rohit I have edited to show one option using `dirname`, which you may have on your system, or a native bash method.

Comment: Thanks. bash part is working and what if I want to create new dir which drives it name from variable like ($COMMITCODE$USERID) and copy into that directory. sorry i am new to shell so having hard time to figure out things.

Comment: If you want to make a new directory using those variables, you could use something like `dir="$commitcode/$userid/${file%/*}"` - is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. This is what i wanted. Thanks Tom, really appreciated your help.

Comment: @rohit you're welcome. If your problem is solved, don't forget to accept my answer by clicking on the tick mark next to it.